# Why are the java.net package not accessible in the BeanShell Sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Initially all the imports were working fine until I closed and re-opened the script after which the color of few import statement has changed and are giving error when running the script.

[image]

See above, the some classes are showing black and some in golden. The ones in black are giving the beanshell exception.
It was working but suddenly after closing and re-opening the script has created this chaos.

Can someone explain this weird behaviour...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Beanshell User Manual](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html)

> **Default Imports**
>
> By default, common Java core and extension packages are imported for you. They
> are, in the order in which they are imported:
>
> - javax.swing.event
> - javax.swing
> - java.awt.event
> - java.awt
> - java.net
> - java.util
> - java.io
> - java.lang
>
> Two BeanShell package classes are also imported by default:
>
> - bsh.EvalError
> - bsh.Interpreter

So basically you don't need to import these "in black" packages.

[image: JMeter Beanshell Without Import]

It is also possible to use "super import" to load the entire classpath like:

```
import *;
```

In order to get to the bottom of your script failure either add [`debug()` directive](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) to the beginning of your script - this way you will get comprehensive debugging information in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) or put your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Beanshell failure", ex);
}
```

This way you will get "normal" [stacktrace](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Stack_trace) in *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more details.

---

Also be aware that since JMeter 3.1 [it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would recommend considering moving to Groovy, it is more Java compliant, has nice [SDK enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) and its performance is much higher.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, 
The try-catch helped me identify the error. My URL was incorrect.
The black and golden color does not really matter.